# Django | .update и ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, orm

Имеем модели:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    match_id = models.IntegerField('Номер матча', null='true', blank='true')
    date_time = models.DateTimeField('Дата начала', auto_now_add=True)
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(to='teams.Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='teams_1', blank='true', null='true')
....
```

и

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.IntegerField('Номер команды', null='true', blank='true')
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50)
...
```

У меня есть список матчей из внешнего файла и я хочу обновлять его. Делаю примерно так:

```
update_match = Match.objects.filter(match_id=id_m).update(match_id=15, date_time='eg', team_1=10)
```

Всё работает, кроме поля team_1. Там по умолчанию идет поиск команды с номером 10 по полю id в базе, а мне надо сравнивать с полем team_id. Кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: Подозреваю, что здесь `.update(match_id=15, date_time='eg', team_1=10)` нужен инстанс `Team`

Comment: Сделал вот так. Работает, но не уверен что так правильно: .update(match_id=15, date_time='eg', team_1=Team.objects.get(team_id=10))

Comment: Это правильное решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обновить поле `team_1`, нужно передать ему экземпляр объекта (а не число 10). В вашем случе:

```
team = Team.objects.get(team_id=10)
update_match = Match.objects.filter(match_id=id_m).update(match_id=15, date_time='eg', team_1=team)
```